# What is the meaning of $\forall x: \exists y:(x+y=0)$?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

**Domain sets:**

x = [1 2 3]
y = [-1 -4 -5]

For all x there exists at least one y that satisfies x + y = 0.

**Evaluation:**

A:

```
1 + -1 = 0 ok
1 + -4 = 0
1 + -5 = 0
```

B:

```
2 + -1 = 0
2 + -4 = 0
2 + -5 = 0
```

C:

```
3 + -1 = 0
3 + -4 = 0 
3 + -5 = 0
```

Should one from A or B or C be true, or one from A and B and C?

Comment: Using your own words, the latter is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written $\forall x\exists y : x+y=0$ requires at least one in each of A, B *and* C to be correct.

If we only require one to be correct in A, B *or* C the expression becomes $\exists x\exists y : x+y=0$.

Thus, for your domain sets, the first (your) statement is false and the second is true.

Comment: Could I write $∃x∃y:x+y=0$ to $∃(x,y)(x+y=0)$ or is this very unconvential?

Comment: That is fine. In the same way we can group $\forall$ quantifiers.